# Back Button Issue in Android Webview

Tags: android, android-webview

THe problem is little difficult to convey, The Actual scenario will be help you guys to understand the real problem.

In the Android Application.

I have a lot of the Jquery Mobile Page append to the android Webview.

When i select one Page (E.g) Profile , the page opens properly and if i press the back button, the application moves to the main page, if i again select profile and press back the application goes to the login page.

if i select some other page and select the profile this is not happening. this issue is not only with the single page. in all the page i have the same issue. Can some one guide me what should i have do?

The Source code of the Key Press event,
    enter code here

```
   @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && webview.isEnabled()
            && !this.onLogin) {

        webview.loadUrl("javascript:handleDeviceBack()");
        return true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && this.onLogin) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:handleDeviceHome()");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In my web view,

```
enter code here
 handleDeviceBack = function(status) {
mHealth.util.logMessage('On device Back');
var historyBack = {
    "home" : "page",
    "loginPage" : "page",
    "welcomeMsg" : "page"
};
var moduleIndex = {
    "assessNotFound" : "../../home/view/home.html",
    "showActivity" : "../../home/view/home.html",
    "showMessage" : "../../home/view/home.html",
    "show_tracker" : "../../home/view/home.html",
    "settingsPage" : "../../home/view/home.html"
};
var graphPages = {
    "singlehealthdatapage" : "page",
    "multiplehealthdatapage" : "page"
};
var otherShortcuts = {
    "show_tracker_view" : "../../trackers/view/showtracker.html",
    "detailMessage" : "../../messages/view/showmessage.html",
    "alfrescoDIV" : "../../messages/view/showmessage.html"
};
// var exitAppCriteria={ "home" : "page","loginPage" : "page","welcomeMsg" :
// "page"};

if($('.ui-page-active').attr('id')=="condition_index")
    {
        $.mobile.changePage("../../home/view/history.html");
    }
else if (historyBack[$('.ui-page-active').attr('id')]
        || $('body').children().is('#tandcPage')) {
    Android.finishActivity();
} else if (moduleIndex[$('.ui-page-active').attr('id')]) {
    Android.highlightHome();
    $('.ui-alert-wallpaper').detach();
    $.mobile.changePage(moduleIndex[$('.ui-page-active').attr('id')]);

} else if (graphPages[$('.ui-page-active').attr('id')]) {
    Android.showTab();
    Android.pageHistory();
} else if (otherShortcuts[$('.ui-page-active').attr('id')]) {
    $.mobile.changePage(otherShortcuts[$('.ui-page-active').attr('id')]);
} else {

    $('.dw').detach();
    $('.dwo').detach();
    $('.dw').detach();
    $('.ui-alert-wallpaper').detach();
    Android.showTab();
    Android.pageHistory();
}
```

};

I found the problem is with the Android.pageHistory();

```
enter code here
    public void pageHistory() {
    this.activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            WebContainerActivity.webview.goBack();

        }
    });

}
```

Where First time its running properly but if the function called repeatly the web view.go back to the first page.

Comment: what is your goal ? what do u want to do ? what is the thing that must be?

Comment: Even time when i press the device back button from the particular page, it should always goes to the same page. I pasting the code so that we will have some picture of what is the exact problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard coded the URL by their ID and solved the issue temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

In your activity override backpressed method like this

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
      webview.loadUrl(sameurl);
        }
```

Comment: No lucky, the same problem happening. this issue is when we press the back button two times, the application go back to the first page.